# VS Code regex replace

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I want to do a global find of all instances of

`TestBed.get(*)`

and replace with

`TestBed.inject<*>(*)`

I can't seem to figure out the regex I need to just match what is between the brackets

I have tried `TestBed.get(.*)` and replace with `TestBed.inject<$1>($1)` but the ends up with an extra set of brackets

Comment: Try `TestBed.get\((.*)\)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to escape the literal `(` and `)`

```
TestBed.get\(([^)]*)\)
```

Comment: For reference, the `[^)]` component ensures that the closing parentheses is not captured as part of the greedy capture group with `*`.

Answer (score 0):

In `TestBed.get(.*)` the brackets are considered for making the groups. So you need to escape those. Try finding this instead:

```
TestBed.get(\(.*)\)
```

Also instead of a wild card pattern, you may want to use more precise patterns to match the contents inside the brackets.